# CSS handling sizes when changing mobile's system font size

Tags: android, html, css, typescript, mobile

I couldn't find anywhere a good solution to overcome a bad UI when the user changes the system's font size in mobile.

I want texts, buttons and whatever to stay in a reasonable size (not too small and not huge) to display a nice UI without anything overlap each other or cut out of the screen. I know how to do that normally, but not when the system's font size is changed (i.e: not related to screen\container width).

For instance:

1. If I have a title ***My Title Example*** I can always split it to 2-3 lines.
2. If I have a title ***Registration***, it spreads almost all over the width of an average mobile screen. Changing the system's font size will cause a weird display. Obviously, I don't want to ellipsis it (i.e ***Regist...***).

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can consider using `em` or `rem` units in your CSS values to have your elements react to the font size

Comment: The elements react well to the changes. I would like to limit the growth\shrink ratio to avoid the mentioned problem

Comment: You can consider using the [`clamp()` CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp) for that

Comment: You can add breakpoints into your words with this unicode character `&shy;`
This character is not rendered visibly; instead, it suggests a place where the browser might choose to break the word if necessary.
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/

Comment: @AngYC I tried using clamp(). But for that to work I need to know the min-max values, which varies with each mobile device (screen dimensions, pixles density..). Do you have a working example?

Comment: @Sebi I don't want to break the word. I want to control its size

Comment: If a user wants their text to be so large that "Registration" doesn't fit on the screen, and you therefore want to override the user's wishes so that it fits on the screen anyway... why? What is it about your UI that has to look good *at the cost of overriding* a user's preferences and/or accessibility needs?

Comment: @JSmart523 I want the text to be bigger, as the user's wish. But I also don't want it to be so big that it doesn't fit the screen (or overlap other elements). If the user can't see or understand the text, how does it help him?

Comment: It is possible to structure CSS so that, when a user changes font size, the page adjusts without elements overlapping. If a user can't see the text without making it so huge the word "Registration" doesn't fit on their screen, wouldn't they rather have to scroll to read the word than be unable to make the word large enough?

Comment: Correct. How can I configure a CSS like that? How can it know the user changed it?

Comment: So that they have to scroll? [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow). So that your page layout is responsive? The cool kids these days use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) or [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout), but the way I learned was to style navigation items with `display: block; float: right` so they appeared next to each other if there was room, otherwise started a new line.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I though you had a different idea in mind. Yes, scrolling and moving components responsively is easy. Breaking words into multiple lines is ugly and I would prefer to control the amount of growth\shrinkage of the text if possible. What is the best practice?

Comment: Hi @lior_13, added an example in answer as per your request on how to make use of it.

Answer (score 1):

`em` and `rem` is a good place to start when building responsive UI that depends on the font size of the user.

As discussed over the comments in the question, we can take into considerations of screen dimensions and pixels density as well to make sure the UI is always visible to a certain extent. Luckily, there's also other units such as `vw`, `vh`, `vmin`, `vmax` to ensure it looks good enough in the viewport.

Here's an example that should try its best to fit everything in all scenarios, and is respecting user's default font-size except when the device is too small:

```css
/* The main magic is here, rem refers to the font-size specified by html */
html {
  font-size: min(4vw, 1rem);
}

/* Use rem / em everywhere in your design */
h1 {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  height: 3em;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div {
  background: green;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0.5rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
}

/* Other styles that are irrelevant */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      The layout will try to scale proportionally when the width is too small
    </h1>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```